Can the velocity of approach be negative?
Can the velocity of approach be negative? Suppose in an oblique collision question, a particle of mass $m$ has an initial impact parameter $d$ to a ball of mass $m$ and radius $R$ at rest, which is moving with a velocity $u$ towards it and it collides.
So in order to calculate the post collision velocities we can use:

Momentum conservation along the common normal
Coefficient of restitution equation
The concept that tangential velocities will not change.

Now while writing the equation of coefficient of restitution should I write
$$e=\frac{\mathrm{Velocity\  of\  separation}}{-u\sin(\alpha)} $$
OR
$$e=\frac{\mathrm{Velocity\  of\  separation}}{+u\sin(\alpha)} $$
Since it's an oblique collision, everyone knows what is the angle $\alpha$.  When writing $-u\sin\alpha$ the answer comes wrong whereas if I write $+u\sin\alpha$ it's correct, why is that? Any explanations please?

Negative velocities are velocities in the other direction. If you travel $-5 m/s$ towards me it's the same as traveling $5 m/s$ away from me.
Inputting a negative value for velocity of approach means that the projectile is getting farther away, not approaching at all. So there wouldn't be any collision. Any mathematical expression about what happens after the collision will be meaningless.
Whenever possible in kinematics problems, sketch and label a diagram - it'll help a lot to avoid nonsense inputs like a projectile moving away from the thing it's supposed to collide with (prior to the collision).
